# How can i set up Dynamic DNS updates for servers running on openstack with floating IPs?

Tags: domain-name-system, openstack

I have an openstack deployment running in the company LAN. It's segregated internally into projects for the various departments with internal LANs for each project, and floating IP allocation is dynamic and comes from a company network address pool.

for example - Project DEV has internal network "dev_net_01" with addresses 10.1.1.0/24 and some machines on that network get manually assigned a floating IP such as 192.168.1.1/24 (which is the company network IP segment)

Now, I want the machines to be available for users in the company LAN via DNS names which will point to the floating IPs and I need it dynamic so that I don't have to manually create the DNS records in the company DNS each time a machine is created or removed.

How can I do that? The machines inside openstack are not aware of their floating IPs so i need some kind of tool that either sits on openstack or a tool that can update DNS servers via command line.

I've seen the openstack DNSaaS module (Designate) and it appears to be doing what I need, but it seems way too complex for my purposes. Don't feel like buying and maintaining a dairy farm for my daily glass of milk..

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some DDNS providers such as [DuckDNS](https://www.duckdns.org/) automatically [detect the IP](https://www.duckdns.org/install.jsp). I suppose want to stay in your internal LAN so you can't use DuckDNS, but you should be able to implement similar functionality yourself.